# Torrent Tracker response seems not well formated

Tags: c#, bittorrent, torrent

Today I try to understand (and maybe to implement) the Bittorrent Protocol.

I already well understood how to "decrypt" the content of a .torrent file and I sent a request to a Tracker with the extracted datas.

But, the response is not the expected one: [The wiki about the Bittorent Tracker Protocol](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrent_Tracker_Protocol#Response_Format) says that the response must contain, in the "peers" `List of dictionaries corresponding to peers.`

I am reading the response with a C# program and the only thing I have in the field is a Byte Array (byte[]) that contains `50-0B-3F-3F-00-00-50-0B-3F-3F-3F-3F` if I convert it to a string with

```csharp
BitConverter.ToString((byte[])peers)
```

The original response of the Tracker is:

`d8:completei0e10:downloadedi2e10:incompletei2e8:intervali1970e12:min intervali985e5:peers12:P??  P????e`

And my HTTP request to it was:

`http://bt1.archive.org:6969/announce?info_hash=%ac%c3%b2%e43%d7%c7GZ%bbYA%b5h%1c%b7%a1%ea%26%e2&peer_id=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST&ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx&port=6881&downloaded=0&left=970`

So I don't understand, what is wrong ?

Comment: Did you actually read the first line of that wiki? The tracker can send one of two kinds of response, as a [BEncoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode) dictionary

Comment: My bad, I missed this part...
So, whatever, If i understand well the response, the Tracker sent me 2 IP ?

50-0B-3F-3F-00-00 and 50-0B-3F-3F-3F-3F ->  80.11.63.63:0000 and 80.11.63.63:6363 ?

Answer (score 1):

The tracker response is in `compact=1`-form, which is more or less mandatory nowadays.

Specified here: [BEP23 - Tracker Returns Compact Peer Lists](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0023.html)